# How can I assign a set of non-sequential integers to an array that was created with malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I specify, "non-sequential" because I'm aware that I can use a for loop to fill in the values in the case that the set of numbers are sequential. But I'm unaware of how to assign the values when the values have no relation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  // edited in for the use of memcpy


int main()
{
    static const size_t kBufferSize = 6;

    int *nums = malloc(kBufferSize * sizeof(int));
```

I'm aware that this will not work:

```
    //nums[] = { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 }; incorrect
    memcpy(nums, (int []){ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 }, kBufferSize * sizeof(int)); // corrected
```

because I'm reallocating the array without using the malloc'ed array, producing a memory leak.

```
    int *reversed = malloc(kBufferSize * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < kBufferSize; i++)
    //  reversed[4 - i] = nums[i];   incorrect
        reversed[5 - i] = nums[i]; //corrected
    free(nums);

    for (int i = 0; i < kBufferSize; i++)
        printf("%i\n", reversed[i]);    
    free(reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in more general terms what you're trying to achieve; it's not essential that your storing "non-sequential" numbers for example, or it it?

Comment: Are you looking for this: `memcpy(nums, (int []){ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 }, kBufferSize * sizeof(int));` -- Please explain clearly what you wants?

Comment: `nums[0] = 4; nums[1] = 8; nums[15]; ...`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Yes, I'm looking for something more along the lines of what's in your comment.

Comment: @user2270773 then give it a try if you are using new compiler its possible in C99

Comment: Read this answer [How to set value of unsigned char array on C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18259950/1673391)

Comment: @delnan I've tried that, but after it prints out the numbers, I get an error: glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I got the same error for your suggestion: glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Comment: @user2270773 Then you're doing something wrong. Perhaps freeing a pointer twice.

Comment: `reversed[4 - i] = nums[i];` - I don't like that 4 considering i goes from 0 to 5.

Comment: @user2270773 check this is working  [@codepad](http://codepad.org/P2yzy5Z2)

Comment: @aragaer You're correct, the code was initially 5 sequential values. I added an extra value and forgot to change that part of the code. delnan and GrijeshChauhan You're suggestions worked, although delnan that suggestion could become problematic with a much longer list of integers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values you have are already in array-like state, why not just put them to a (temporary) local array and then copy?

```
static const size_t kBufferSize = 6;

int *nums = malloc(kBufferSize * sizeof(int));

{
    int data[] = { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };
    memcpy(nums, data, sizeof(data));
}
```

Which is actually the same as @[Grijesh Chauhan's suggestion](http://codepad.org/P2yzy5Z2) but slightly more readable.

Comment: I'm a beginner at C, if that wasn't already obvious. And I'm trying to be more precise with memory management. The code was initially setup the way you have here, but without `memcpy`.

Comment: because you have provided an answer, I'll accept your answer because, while your comment builds upon GrijeshChauhan's answer in his comment, you pointed out part of the problem which fixed my code.